# How to use color from one class as background-color in a second class for the same element?

Tags: html, css

For a project I'm working on we need to define a set of buttons.
Each button is expected to have a border and a text color in the same color and a transparent background. So a blue button has blue border and blue text, a yellow button a yellow border and text.

The classes are defined as

```
.btn, a.btn {
   @apply .py-2 .px-4 .rounded .no-underline;

   &\:blue {
     @apply .bg-transparent .text-blue;

     &:hover {
       @apply .bg-transparent .text-blue-lightest;
     }
   }

   &\:yellow  {
     @apply .bg-transparent .text-yellow .border-2 .border-yellow;

     &:hover {
       @apply .text-blue-lightest .border-2 .border-blue-lightest;
     }
   }
...
```

And we use them as such

```
<div class="btn btn:blue ...>...</div>
```

Now in some cases we have what we would like to call a "primary button", which has a fill color and a white text. As we do not want to make a complete set of primary buttons we wanted to try if we can "inherit" the color of another class and use that as background color.
in code:

```
<div class="btn btn:blue btn:primary ...">...</div>
```

So we want btn:primary to take the color of btn:blue and use that one as background-color and make the text white.

I was able to find a solutions using currentColor for background-color but this interferes with the property color: white; in btn:primary as it will take the white color as "currentColor".
The only work around I was able to find was to wrap the text of the button inside a span and give it a class which makes the text white.
Is there any way I can achieve this result by only once defining btn:primary so that it inherits the color of btn:blue (or btn:yellow or btn:red or ...) AND making the text white by not wrapping the button text inside its own tags?
Ow, we're using tailwind, thought this might be useful information.

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, there's not really a *good* way to do what you want. `border` inherits the `color`, just like `currentColor` does, so you can trim some class requirements down that way. But you need to put the attributes in there somewhere, and I don't see why a `.primary span { color: white; }` wrapper situation wouldn't be ideal to achieve your end goal.

Take the snippet below, the markup is relatively straightforward. At the end I've included a button that sort of does what you want by abusing the `:before` pseudo-class and removing the text content from the button. For SEO and Usability purposes you may want to use `.hack-button { font-size: 0; }` and `.hack-button:before { font-size: 12px; }` and keep the text in both places.

Personally I'd stick with a simple wrapper that overwrites `currentColor` instead of using pseudo elements. You could probably achieve what you want with some JavaScript as well, but truthfully it's probably easier to just wrap the button content in a span and call it a day.

```css
.button,
.hack-button {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.primary { background: currentColor; }
.primary span { color: #fff; }

.blue  { color: #0095ee; }
.red   { color: #ee3300; }
.green { color: #009933; }
.gray { color: #ccc; }

.hack-button:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a class="button blue primary" href="#"><span>Blue Primary</span></a>
<a class="button blue" href="#"><span>Blue Secondary</span></a>
<br />
<a class="button red primary" href="#"><span>Red Primary</span></a>
<a class="button red" href="#"><span>Red Secondary</span></a>
<br />
<a class="button green primary" href="#"><span>Green Primary</span></a>
<a class="button green" href="#"><span>Green Secondary</span></a>
<br />
<a class="button gray primary" href="#"><span class="dark">Gray Primary</span></a>
<a class="button gray" href="#"><span>Gray Secondary</span></a>
<br />
<a class="hack-button blue primary" href="#" data-content="Hacked Primary"></a>
```

Comment: Thx. In the end we decides to keep it easy and use the span methode.